# C++ memory leak in linked-list push_front and push_back

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind, doubly-linked-list

I'm getting this memory leak error by valgrind:

```
 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 11        
 at 0x4C2C21F: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
   by 0x413E47: pjc::list::push_back(double) (list.cpp:33)
   by 0x416371: ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____4() (tests-list-01.cpp:86)

24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 11
   at 0x4C2C21F: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
   by 0x414047: pjc::list::push_front(double) (list.cpp:66)
   by 0x4192C1: ____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____10() (tests-list-01.cpp:146)
```

My `.hpp` file for linked list looks like this:

```
using std::size_t;

namespace pjc {

class list {
private:
    struct node {
        double val = 0;
        node* prev = nullptr;
        node* next = nullptr;
    };

    node* head = nullptr;
    node* tail = nullptr;
    size_t num_elements = 0;

public:
    list() = default;
    list(const list& rhs);
    list& operator=(const list& rhs);
    list(list&& rhs);
    list& operator=(list&& rhs);
    ~list();

    void push_back(double elem);

    void push_front(double elem); 
};
```

And definitions of `push_back()`, `push_front()` and the destructor of the linked-list look like this:

```
list::list(const list &rhs) {
    head = tail = nullptr;
    for(node* tmp = rhs.head; tmp!=NULL; tmp=tmp->next) {
        push_back(tmp->val);
    }
    num_elements = rhs.num_elements;
}

list::~list() {
    node *T = head;
    while(T != nullptr)
    {
        node *T2 = T;
        T = T->next;
        delete T2;
    }
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    num_elements = 0;
}

void list::push_back(double elem) {
    node *n = new node;
    n->val = elem;
    if(tail == nullptr)
    {
        head = n;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = n;
        n->prev = tail;
        tail = n;
    }
    num_elements++;
}

void list::push_front(double elem) {
    node *n = new node;
    n->val = elem;
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = n;
        tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
        head->prev = n;
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }
    num_elements++;
}
list &list::operator=(const list &rhs) {
    list temp(rhs);
    std::swap(head, temp.head);
    std::swap(tail, temp.tail);
    std::swap(num_elements, temp.num_elements);
    return *this;
}

list::list(list &&rhs) {
    head = rhs.head;
    tail = rhs.tail;
    num_elements = rhs.num_elements;

    rhs.head = nullptr;
    rhs.tail = nullptr;
    rhs.num_elements = 0;
}

list &list::operator=(list &&rhs) {
    this->~list(); // Destroy our current contents
    std::swap(head, rhs.head);
    std::swap(tail, rhs.tail);
    std::swap(num_elements, rhs.num_elements);
    return *this;
}
```

I tried to change the destructor, but it seem to be OK. I really don't have and ideas whatsoever where the leak happens.

EDIT: Sorry, i left out some important parts of the code for the first time. Now it should follow the rule of 5.

Comment: What catches the eye is the violation of the rule of three.

Comment: IOW, you are missing a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.  And in fact, this code is clearly using C++11 or later, so you need to follow the rule of five, which includes adding a move constructor and move assignment operator as well.

Comment: Maybe use smart pointers instead of raw pointers?  Or use the std::list instead of implementing your own doubly linked list?

Comment: One of the best ways to grasp the linked list (or any other pointer-driven structure) is to draw pictures. Draw what you want the list to look like. If you find yourself drawing stuff you didn't code, that's a bug. Then follow your code to the letter and try to draw the same list. If you can't, that's a bug and you probably know where it is.

Comment: @Slava "*Now look into your code - do you do all 3 things? No you do not*" - actually, it does.

Comment: Could we trouble you for a [mcve]? I recommend focusing the MCVE on one of `push_back` or `push_front` because the solution for one will likely apply to the other.

Comment: @JanVanke your use of `this->~list();` inside of `operator=(list&&)` is illegal. You can't call a destructor explicitly like that, unless you use [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to allocate the object being destroyed (which you are not doing). If you want to clear the list explicitly, implement a `clear()` method for that purpose, which you can then call when needed, like inside of `~list` and `operator=`

Comment: @JanVanke However, after adding the new code to your question, you haven't indicated whether the memory leak is still occurring or not. And you still have not provided any code showing how you are using your `list` class in the rest of your project. Please provide a [mcve] that produces a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing in the code you have shown that leaks, but you have not shown all of your relevant code.

For instance, HOW you use `list` objects may be contributing to the cause of the leak.  For instance, if you are not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) by implementing proper copy and move constructors, and copy and move assignment operators, then you can leak memory when copying/moving `list` objects.  But you did not show that code, so we can't tell if you are doing things correctly or not.

That being said, your destructor does have an extra `delete` that does not belong, and your `push_back()` and `push_front()` methods can be simplified.

The safest option is to simply use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and let it manage memory for you.  But, if you want to do it manually, then try this:

```
class list
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        double val;
        node* prev = nullptr;
        node* next = nullptr;

        node(double value = 0) : val(value) {}
    };

    node* head = nullptr;
    node* tail = nullptr;
    size_t num_elements = 0;

public:
    list() = default;
    list(const list &src);
    list(list &&src);
    ~list();

    list& operator=(const list &rhs);
    list& operator=(list &&rhs);

    void push_back(double elem);
    void push_front(double elem);

    void swap(list &other)
};
```

```
list::list(const list &src)
    : list()
{
    for(node *n = src.head; n != nullptr; n = n->next)
        push_back(n->val);
}

list::list(list &&src)
    : list()
{
    src.swap(*this);
}

list::~list()
{
    node *n = head;
    while (n)
    {
        node *next = n->next;
        delete n;
        n = next;
    }
}

list& list::operator=(const list &rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
        list(rhs).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

list& operator=(list &&rhs)
{
    list(std::move(rhs)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

void list::push_back(double elem)
{
    node *n = new node(elem);
    if (tail)
    {
        tail->next = n;
        n->prev = tail;
    }
    else
        head = n;
    tail = n;
    ++num_elements;
}

void list::push_front(double elem)
{
    node *n = new node(elem);
    if (head)
    {
        head->prev = n;
        n->next = head;
    }
    else
        tail = n;
    head = n;
    ++num_elements;
}

void list::swap(list &other)
{
    std::swap(head, other.head);
    std::swap(tail, other.tail);
    std::swap(num_elements, other.num_elements);
}
```

Comment: @WhozCraig done

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
template<typename T>
class List {
private:
    Node<T>* head = nullptr;
    Node<T>* tail = nullptr;

    std::size_t _size = 0;

public:

    List() = default;

    // copy constructor
    List(const List<T>& l) {
        _size = l._size;
        Node<T>* current = nullptr;
        Node<T>* previous = nullptr;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < l._size; ++i) {
            current = new Node<T>(l[i].data);
            current->prev = previous;
            if (previous) {
                previous->next = current;
            } else {
                head = current;
            }
            previous = current;
        }
        tail = current;
    }

    // assignment operator
    List<T>& operator=(const List<T>& l) {
        if (l.isEmpty()) {
            this->clear();
            return *this;
        }

        // keeps existing nodes intact, and only changes their value
        while (_size > l.size()) {
            Node<T>* prev = tail->prev;
            delete tail;
            prev->next = nullptr;
            tail = prev;
            --_size;
        }

        Node<T>* temp = head;
        Node<T>* tempL = l.head;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < _size; ++i) {
            temp->data = tempL->data;
            temp = temp->next;
            tempL = tempL->next;
        }

        while (_size < l._size) {
            this->append(tempL->data);
            tempL = tempL->next;
            ++_size;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    ~List() {
        Node<T>* temp = head;
        while (temp) {
            Node<T>* next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = next;
        }
    }

    void append(const T& value) {
        auto* temp = new Node<T>(value);
        if (!head) {
            // no head also means no tail
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        } else {
            tail->next = temp;
            temp->prev = tail;
            tail = temp;
        }
        ++_size;
    }

    void prepend(const T& value) {
        auto* temp = new Node<T>(value);
        temp->next = head;
        if (head) {
            head->prev = temp;
        }
        head = temp;
        ++_size;
    }
};
```

That said, you should probably follow the Rule of Three and implement a copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Since this code is using C++11 or later, it should really follow the Rule of Five instead.